# bpf_helpers.h file is missing

Tags: centos, ebpf

I'm trying to run some example XDP code that depends on bpf_helpers.h and the file is missing.

The distribution is CentOS 8.0 with kernel 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 with CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS=y. I've installed the kernel and kernel-devel packages and the header/library are not there.

Anyone know the package ?

Comment: It's a standalone file, not a package. Are you trying to compile the samples in the kernel sources or others?

Comment: No it's not a kernel sample, just has references to kernel source

Comment: CentOS doesn't provide any packages that include those headers, they're not part of the kernel headers or kernel source used on CentOS 8.  You can always grab it from the upstream kernel git and try to use it, but there's no guarentee it'll work with the CentOS kernel.